# How to debug large file upload error on IIS website (using Joomla)

Tags: asp.net, xml, joomla, iis-8

I have seen many questions asking the same thing, and this trick seemed to work for them, but not in my case.

I have been tasked with setting up a webpage on a company's server for training videos. I can't embed them from a site such as YouTube because they contain sensitive information. 
The webpage has been set up using Joomla on Windows Server 2012. This is the first time I've ever experienced IIS since I only have experience with Apache.

The files I am trying to upload are just under 1GB. When I attempt to upload, I get **Error Total size of upload exceeds the limit**.

Here is what I have placed in the web.config file (since there isn't a php.ini file):

```
<configuration>
     <system.web>
          <!-- this is my edit -->
          <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
     </system.web>
<location path=".">
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- this is my other edit -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

I go into CMD and enter "**iisreset**" to restart, and it still gives me the same error.

I also found forums where people were advising a change with maxRequestLength, so I also wrote this in the config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>
```

Still no dice. The client is becoming very impatient since they still haven't received what they asked for. We originally tried to place the videos on their Wordpress site, but that didn't work either since it is on a shared hosting server.

I found [**this**](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-debug.htm) webpage that instructed me (at the bottom) to run a program on the server, but I don't know how to do that yet. I unzipped it and it opened in Visual Studio. No idea where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this the main web.config you are editing or a subfolder on the server?  I had an issue exactly like this and a web.config that was located higher in the heirarchy had allowOverride="false".  When that happens, it is preventing you from changing those settings and must be changed to true.

Comment: The path is C: -> Users -> Administrator -> Documents -> joomla -> web.config

Comment: If this isn't the directory you speak of, where can I find the main one?

Comment: I have not worked with joomla specifically, but usually the main web.config is under c:\inetpub\ or c:\inetpub\htdocs.  If you're not seeing it under that location, check `inetmgr` , right click and go to explore

Comment: I found that file as well. Still nothing.

Comment: The last part of your question you can achieve likely with your existing code.  All you need to do with that .aspx is drop it on the server, then open it, from the server itself.  You'd be going to localhost/folderMaybe/debug-upload.aspx or your existing file.  Does it give you more details when you do run this on the server?